# How to hide/show text selection controls from textformfield when scroll to up and down list?

Tags: listview, singlechildscrollview, flutter-textformfield

I am using flutter channel stable 3.0.2 version,
I am facing issue in text selection controls (like cut, paste ) scroll to up when scrolling list , how to resolve it? please help me, I have attach video of facing issue. [text selection control hide/show issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCyK1.png)